# Ubuntu installation from usb restarts again and again

Tags: ubuntu, installation, usb

I am trying to install `ubuntu` through my **usb stick**.I have done all the steps to create `usb` `bootable`.
Now when i restart my laptop it ask me for installation and then choosing a language as soon as i go to step where i am asked this Install them side by side my laptop restarts and the whole process is repeated again.Where am I going wrong?

Comment: if i assume you correctly once the installation process is finished and after that it's getting restart ? right ?

Comment: no when i select install ubuntu with windows

Answer (score 0):

it might be because your boot priority is set for usb device !
so once you finish the installation process it will ask you to restart as soon it get restart it will check the boot priority settings and it founds the boot able usb on your system . so again it will repeat the process .

[Boot Priority settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWbRl.gif)

what you can do is once you finish the installation process and it will ask for restart just remove the usb so it load the operating system !!

Hope this helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

I think there will be issue in creating bootable USB stick try this free ware tools http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ and recreate bootable stick. Hope this will help, might be you have an issue with bootable process. and make sure the image you are using to create bootable should not be corrupted and with missing files.
Thanks